# Transform a non-monotonic value before decision tree (concrete example)?

Tags: data-transformation, feature-selection, feature-engineering, natural-language

Newbie question here.  I am building a toy decision tree to differentiate personal names from business, government, or organizational names, like:

AAA ENTERPRISES LLC DBA AAA BBB SERVICE
SMITH BARBARA
EXAMPLE FLOOR COVERINGS
BROWN JOSEPH A
2013 HOLDINGS L L C

I'm mainly using continuous values, such as the # of tokens, the length of the string, and the % of tokens which are "dictionary words."

However, I've noticed by eyeballing the data that if there are one or two trailing singleton chars (as in "BROWN JOSEPH A" or "HUTTON E F"), it's often a name, whereas if there are more than two, it's often a business (like "2013 HOLDINGS L L C").

The value of this signal is non monotonic and probably goes like this:

```
Num Singletons:    Relative size of effect:
0                  0
1                  +Large
2                  +Smaller but positive
3                  -Moderate
4                  -Large
```

I recall reading about "recentering" although this isn't quite exactly what I need, I fear.  But I'm fairly confident there is a well-known technique for handling these non-monotonic suspected correlations early in the processing / transformation pipeline.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Heavy lifting not required, just looking for a Wiki or CV link, or a couple terms of art I can Google.

Answer (score 2):

Since number of trailing single characters is an integer and will probably be mostly 0, 1, 2 ... and probably never larger than 5, you could treat it as categorical. That will let the tree algorithm break it anywhere.

Comment: Thank you.  Since I am using Scikit, and I understand it to require categoricals to be coded as multiple dichotomies or one-hot encoding, this will give me several more features.  I wonder if, generally, changing a discrete (integer) measure to categorical in this way presents a dimensionality curse challenge?

Comment: It depends on how many times you do it and how many dichotomies there are.